# Replacement for ITemplate in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am currently running a website, i use a control that inherits from ITemplate to wrap all my usercontrols in.

basically what it is, is a table with a nice border, and i am able to dump anything in there, so if i change the container template, all the containers accross the site changes...

I am now in the process of rebuilding the entire application using MVC 2, does anyone know of a way i can achieve the same "Container" like template in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed Thanx here is an example:

```
public static class Block
{
    public static BlockHelper BeginBlock(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper content, string title)
    {
        return new BlockHelper(content, title);
    }
}

public class BlockHelper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper _content;
    private readonly HtmlHelper _title;

    public BlockHelper(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper content, string title)
    {
        _content = content;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<div>");
        sb.Append("<div><h1>" + title + "</h1></div>");
        _content.ViewContext.Writer.Write(sb.ToString());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("</div>");
        _content.ViewContext.Writer.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then i basically uses it as follows:

```
<% using( Html.BeginBlock("TITLE>CONTENT GOES HERE<%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be several ways to do this in MVC, but I would probably suggest using a custom [HTML Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx).

There is an example on how to implement something similar [in this post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx).  Look for the section titled "Creating a DataGrid Helper" in [that post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx) for more information.  I think you will be able to adapt that example to fit your purpose.

Comment: i have been trying to create some sort of an helper to accomplish this.

if one looks at 

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%> 
CONTENT HERE
<% } %>

this basically wraps the content in a form.

does anyone know how that works? all i need is to basically go
<% using (Html.BeginContainer()) {%>
CONTENT HERE
<% } %>

and i want that container to be a div of some sort, that has a class attached to it